# XCTest: The internal class is not casted properly

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, xctest, xctestcase

XCTestCase subclass implementation is below:

```
import XCTest
@testable import AppName

class SomeTestClass: XCTestCase {

    var viewController: AppName.ViewControllerName?
    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("someIdentifier") as? AppName.ViewControllerName // Line 7
        _ = viewController?.view
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
        super.tearDown()
    }

    func testIfCaseInteractionLabelIsNotNil() {
        XCTAssertNotNil(viewController?.someLabel)
    }
}
```

In the code above the type of view controller object is "AppName.ViewControllerName" if I specify it as just ViewControllerName like below, the test fails because of casting in line 7

```
    var viewController: ViewControllerName?
    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("someIdentifier") as? ViewControllerName // Line 7
        _ = viewController?.view
    }
```

I tried making the view controller class public and using @testable annotation in swift2. It doesn't work.

I made "Enable Testability" build setting to YES.

The code works even if I don't use @testable import but in lot of blogs and tutorials, this results in error.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: It sounds like you may have included the storyboard in your test target, in which case remove it.

Comment: No I haven't added the storyboard to my test target

Comment: let viewController1: AppName.ViewControllerName = ViewControllerName()
This line gives a compile time error says "Cannot convert value of ViewControllerName to ViewControllerName"

Comment: I found the problem: I have added ViewControllerName class in the build phases -> Compile sources setting. So I had the same class imported twice
1. During @testable import
2. During compile sources

Comment: removed it from compile sources and now its working. Thanks Mike for the comment